Mock Router ParserError: Expected ';' but got identifier
This mock router is not working. The code is below followed by the error message in bold. I have been calling ^0.8.19 and have updated npm, and checked my hardhat config file and do not see the issue.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

contract MockRouter {
    uint256 public initialPrice;

    constructor(uint256 _initialPrice) {
        initialPrice = _initialPrice;
    }

    function getAmountsOut(uint256 amountIn, address[] calldata path) external pure returns (uint256[] memory amounts) {
        // Create a dynamic memory array with 2 elements
        amounts = new uint256[](2);
        amounts[0] = amountIn;      // Input amount
        amounts[1] = amountIn * 2;  // Example output (mocked calculation)
    }

    function swapExactETHForTokens(
        uint256 amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint256[] memory amounts) {
        require(msg.value > 0, "Must send ETH");

        // Create a dynamic memory array with 2 elements
        amounts = new uint256[](2);
        amounts[0] = msg.value;     // ETH sent
        amounts[1] = msg.value * 2; // Example output (mocked calculation)
    }
}


    *ParserError: Expected ';' but got identifier
      --> contracts/MockRouter.sol:16:36:
  
 |
16 |         amounts = new uint256      amounts[0] = amountIn;
   |                                    ^^^^^^^*


I can compile without problems on Remix
